# Send a value to client using TCP each time click on a button on HTML and javascript, where each button sends a different value

Tags: javascript, html, tcp

I have been jumped into project of my own so that I can learn about networks and apps using networks. However, I am currently stuck at one point and havent yet find a proper answer for that. I am connected to a remote device via TCP. It's listening and I want to send a distinct integer value each time I press A,B, or C. I am able to send a value but only for once and I also dont know how to change it(it only sends the value I already set for it e.g. 32).

For example, I want to send 131 for A, 1118 for B, and 12819 for C. Numbers are just random to examplify the subject.

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Encode Mode<span class="expand">&raquo;</span></a>
            <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#" nowrap>A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" nowrap>B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" nowrap>C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

```
   var net = require('net');

    var setval = 32;

    var buf = new Buffer(1024);
    buf.writeInt32LE(setval, 0); //max value to send 2147483647

    let client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(PORT, IP , () => {
    console.log("Connected");
    client.write(buf); //This will send the byte buffer over TCP
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *html-file* you can create three different buttons with three differents ids

```
<button id="btn1"></button>
<button id="btn2"></button>
<button id="btn3"></button>
```

Then for your buttons make inside your *js-file* three different eventListeners

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', function() {
    const data = {value: 131};
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    await fetch('/startMyFunction', options); 
})
```

The same for the two other buttons with the different values

In your server side js file you have to create a function like this

```
myFunction(val) {

var buf = new Buffer(1024);
buf.writeInt32LE(val, 0); //max value to send 2147483647

// Assumes the connection is established
client.write(buf); //This will send the byte buffer over TCP
});
}
```

Also you have to listen on a path for example

```
app.post('/startMyFunction', (req, res) => {
    // read the parameter out of the request body
    const val = req.body.value
    // Call the function with this parameter
    myFunction(val);
 });
```

The code snippets are (adapted) from my repository, there you can see the full code
https://github.com/CreaTorAlexander/corona-motivator

Comment: Thank you for that solution but I want it to be working without being interrupted not just working for testing.  Can you please suggest a possible solution for that too?

Comment: @mergen I already updated it as the variable *client* is in the global scope it should be possible to call client.write(buf) in the function, assuming the connection is established

Comment: @mergen do you use node here? To call the function on the node server you should take a look at *fetch API* or async / await

Comment: yes I am using node. Still couldn't get it done

Comment: In your node server file index.js you need to create an webserver and then listen on a route like */blaFunction*  from your clients side html file you have to call this api to start the function on the server. Probably this is off topic here, have your already worked with http server or express?

Comment: This is the first time I am working with http server. I have only 1 js file called app.js which connects to a camera as rtsp stream. The things I was asking you were about sending integer values to the ip adress that camera conected to. This should be continuous since I should be sending those integer values at any time without stopping the system.

Comment: the app.js represents your server in this node.js application. The problem is that the part with `document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', function(){myFunction(131)})`is on client side but the function *myFunction()* is on the server side.

Comment: So I am hoping there is a solution for that. I think it will have a similar logic to a chat application. As I want it to be TCP/IP. Could you please help me get through that

Comment: @Alex Couldn't make it working unfortunately

Comment: okay, if you have any questions feel free to ask me

Comment: Sould I be using 2 js-files? I only have one for rtsp using nodejs. Also, where should I place the script snippet "document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', function()"? I read some docs about DOM but couldnt progress at all

Comment: @mergen if you don't want the client side JS be included in your html file then you need a second js file. One representing your server side nodejs file index.js for example and one for your client side activities like DOM Manipulation. Getting the buttons is in the client side script but you could also put it inside your html 
`<script> </script>`

Comment: After I implement the things you showed up there, I can simply send you a github link or share the codes here

Comment: I can take a look at your github repository

Comment: Here are the things I could understand and implement https://github.com/mergen-g/ip-camera/tree/main

Comment: @mergen I made a pull request. In my updated version you can press any of your buttons and it will log the value in your server.

Comment: @ Aalexander Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Nope it just freezes down. I cannot even stream now

Comment: This just make the connection you have to update ist with your stuff

Comment: I know that's what I did

Comment: Yes but it's too long, I cannot post it here

Comment: It will probably also be of-topfic for this question. If you can clarify the problem you can ask a new question.